# Склонение названия города

Tags: грамматика

"В городе Елабуга/ге" - как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Названия городов, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным, как правило, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом: *в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом, **в городе Елабуге***.